# celery tasks are not running

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery, djcelery

I am using celery 3.1.18 with django 1.7 and redis. I am using CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND as redis. But the problem is whenever I push the task to the celery queue. I am not able to see celery-task-meta* key in redis.
Please help

Comment: Can you see the task you are executing in the celery info log? 
>> python manage.py celeryd -l INFO

Comment: No. I am not able to see. After debugging I found that is it because of celery-task-meta-<task id> not being present in the db

Comment: Now the worker is giving this problem. When I start it , it says  **DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 139876350854976 and this is thread id 34516176.**